# Como mantenho a proporção de ImageView no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Tive um problema para a criação de uma SplashScreen. A imagem, 512x512, importada no diretório drawable não mantêm a mesma proporção depois de executado o código. A altura fica maior que a largura, e ajustar manualmente funciona em um aparelho, mas em outro o problema permanece.

Classe SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
    logo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robot);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_up);
    logo.setAnimation(anim);

    //Handler: Aplica as mudanças de interface da SplashScreen
    try {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 4000);
    } catch(Exception e){}
}
public void onBackPressed(){
    this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
 }
```

xml da activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/inicializando"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/inicioTexto"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="315dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/robot"
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inicioTexto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--Nova MainActivity criada -->

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Devo constar, que na prévia do xml a imagem está em sua proporção correta, apenas na compilação ocorre o erro.

Obs: não creio que seja necessário, mas vou disponibilizar o código da animação da imagem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromYDelta="-2000"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é simples, mas realmente é quase uma pegadinha! Você está atribuindo o *background* da ImageView, e, realmente, o background da ImageView não mantém as proporções: ele **sempre** distorce a imagem para caber no ImageView e não o contrário.

No seu XML você faz corretamente (por isso aparece direito em design time):

```
<ImageView
    ...
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/robot"
    ...
    />
```

*Note que deveria usar `src` e não `srcCompat`, pois `src` já é convertido para `srcCompat` automaticamente*.

Contudo, no seu código você usa:

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
logo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robot);
```

E isso causa o problema!

Modifique para:

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.robot);
```

Contudo, como você já atribuiu a imagem em design-time, não deveria nem mesmo precisar atribuí-la novamente em runtime! Veja se não pode remover a linha `logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.robot);` e se tudo não vai funcionar exatamente como esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Já tive alguns problemas com imagens, muitos deles desapareceram com a utilização de um biblioteca chamada [picasso](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/).

Para utilizar, basta inserir nas dependências do `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
.
.
.
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
}
```

Em sua `SplashActivity`, substitua a linha:

```
logo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robot);
```

Para:

```
Picasso.with(getApplication()).load(R.drawable.robot).resize(512, 512).centerCrop().into(logo);
```

Espero ter ajudado.